# The triangle in the $(x,y)$ plane bounded by the lines $y=x, ~y=-x$ and $y=2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to find $\iint_Uf \,d{x}\,d{y} $ where $U$ is the triangle in the $(x,y)$ plane bounded by the lines $y=x, ~y=-x$ and $y=2$ and $f=x+y-2xy$.

My question is how come $x \not \in [-2,2]$? Rather, correct answer is attained by  $x \in [0,2]$.

In other words, why is it $\displaystyle \int_0^{2}\int_{-x}^{x}(x+y-2xy)\,dy\,dx $ and not $\displaystyle \int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-x}^{x}(x+y-2xy)\,dy\,dx $

I've graphed it, and the triangle has vertices $[0,0], ~ [-2,2], ~ [2,2]$ but I still can't see it.

Comment: Why do you think that the range of $x$ values should be $[-2,2] $ when the smallest $x$ value of the vertices is $0$?

Comment: @Eddy But the smallest $x$ in the vertices is $-2$? As in $[x,y] = [-2,2]$ is one of the vertices.

Comment: Oh, sorry, its the y values you've got wrong, as in the posted answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits of the region are:
$$
0<y<2 \qquad \mbox{and}\qquad -y<x-y
$$

so the integral can be written as:
$$
\int_0^2\int_{-y}^{y}(x+y-2xy)dx dy
$$

(Note that the function is symmetric, so you can change $x $ with $y$)

If you  want, you can also write the limits of the region as:
$$
-2<x<2 \qquad \mbox{and}\qquad |x|<y<2
$$

In this case the integral becomes:

$$
\int_{-2}^2\int_{|x|}^{2}(x+y-2xy)dy dx
$$

But it is a bit more difficult to evaluate because it requires a split of the $x$ interval.

Answer (score 1):

Because the function $f$ is symmetric around $y=x$. Indeed:
$$f(-x,y)=f(y,x), \ -2\le x\le 2, -x\le y\le 2; \\
f(x,y)=f(y,x), 0\le x\le 2, x\le y\le 2.$$
So, the volumes under $f$ for the triangles $(-2,2),(0,0),(2,2)$ and $(0,0),(2,-2),(2,2)$ are equal.